# WordPress Redirection not working after Moving to Subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Today I moved my wordpress website from Root Directory to Subdirectory in same domain. I moved all files to new subdirectory. I have also setup 301 wildcard redirection from Hosting cpanel

**301 Wildcard redirection Setting -**

Old Address - `https://www.example.com`

New Address - `https://www.example.com/blog/`

When I am visiting any post directly like `https://www.example.com/blog/this-is-a-post` then it showing correct post without any error but the problem when I am opening the same post without "blog" word i.e. `https://www.example.com/this-is-a-post`  then it also showing correct post instead of redirecting it to `https://www.example.com/blog/this-is-a-post`.

And when I visit through Google then it visiting the old address only i.e. without the word "blog".

One more thing is occuring is redirecting `https://www.example.com` to `https://www.example.com/blog` which is also what I don't want because I have different html index file for homepage

**URL Settings in Wordpress Dashboard -**

WordPress Address (URL) - `https://www.example.com/blog`

Site Address (URL)      - `https://www.example.com/blog`

**Contents of `.htaccess` file:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file. cPanel redirection is very basic and prone to error, it's also likely to have placed the directives in the wrong place (if you are using WordPress).

Comment: Yes I added content of .htaccess file and after adding 301 wildcard redirection through cpanel /blog/ is automatically get added into it

Comment: Did you visit the `/wp-admin/permalinks` page? That one often helps. Have you tried incognito-mode to test? It looks fine to me. You might have something cached in your browser.

Comment: Visit /wp-admin/permalinks/ and hit save again. For whatever reason, this has worked for me in the past.

Comment: I moved wordpress to /blog/ and in root folder I have upload a simple /index/html which says "Welcome to our site but instead of showing that it redirect to example.com/blog

Comment: After removal of .htaccess and index.php file of wordpress from Root directory and removal of 301 redirect from cpanel.. The problem is fixed. Now I have different welcome page in roodex.com and have wordpress blog in roodex,com/blog But Now the problem is When visit through Google search result then Google showing old post url links and after visiting through that it is showing "Not Found" instead of redirecting to new url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After removal of .htaccess and index.php file of wordpress from Root directory and removal of 301 redirect from cpanel.. The problem is fixed. Now I have different welcome page in roodex.com and have wordpress blog in roodex,com/blog **But Now the problem is When visit through Google search result then Google showing old post url links and after visiting through that it is showing "Not Found" instead of redirecting to new url.**

Assuming you are only serving static files from the root of your site (ie. you don't have virtual URLs and a front controller like WordPress) then the best you can do is redirect any request for the root directory (outside of `/blog`) that does not map to a physical file, to your `/blog` subdirectory and hope for the best. If the URL doesn't exist within WordPress either then you'll just get WordPress's 404 page.

I assume you have a `.htaccess` file in the `/blog` subdirectory that handles the WordPress requests?

So, in the `.htaccess` file in the *root of your site* (which I believe is now empty), try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !blog/ /blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK. 301s are cached hard by the browser so can making testing problematic.

Comment: Yes it started redirecting. Will it create problem if i install another php script or landing page or another wordpress cms in Root directory?

Comment: It will cause problems if you install a script that uses a front-controller type pattern (where all non-existent/virtual URLs are rewritten to a script that handles the routeing) - this pretty much includes all CMSs. Because you then wouldn't be able to blindly redirect all non-existent URLs to your `/blog` subdirectory. However, you could perhaps redirect using the 404 of the CMS (not `.htaccess`) - if your CMS allows it. Alternatively, you could redirect all the old URLs individually, unless there is a specific _pattern_ to the old URLs (that would allow you to create a single rule).